# CORS policy error over my ajax request with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, smarty

I tried to send a POST ajax request on my laravel API server to update users data but getting CORS Orgin Error. I am using **Smarty Template Engine**.

**Error:**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2.3/user/updateUserRoles' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Here is my Ajax request

```
$('.user_role').on('click',function(){
    var role_id_and_user_id = $(this).val();
    var func = 'delete';
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        func = 'insert'
    }
    console.log(func);
    $('.loading').show();
    var urlRemote = "{/literal}{$LARAVEL_BASEURL}{literal}/user/updateUserRoles";
    $.ajax({
        url: urlRemote,
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {
            'event': func,
            'role_id': role_id_and_user_id,
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            'Authentication':"Bearer {/literal}{$smarty.session.laravel_token}{literal}",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"*",
         },
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('.loading').hide();
            console.log(responseData);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('.loading').hide();
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    })
    return;
});
```

Comment: Access-Control headers go on the server, not the client.

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you're using laravel. You should give this package a shot for setting CORS for you: https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: Did you edit the file htaccess ? add Access-control in IfModule mod_headers.c

Comment: no i did not edit htaccess yet.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your file request add on top of your code

```
<?php
header(“Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *”);
header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST’);
```

Comment: I tried but not working. getting same error as before.

Comment: can you provide code your API ?